# pass by reference : no known conversion for argument 6 from 'int' to 'int&'

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

I have a function where I pass an argument by reference since I expect the function to edit it. This function is called at several places and I only care about the ref value when called at a particular instance . 
Pseudocode:

```
test_fn(int a, int b, inc , int d, int e, int& ref)
{
//bunch of other functionalities 
//.
//.
ref = (a*b+c)*(d+e);
}

test_fn(1,2,3,4,5,0)//everywhere that I do not care about ref 
int value = 0;
test_fn(1,2,3,4,5, value)//I care about value here and would use it in the remainder of the code .
```

Why can I not pass a 0 directly ? I tried passing a NULL as well and that has a long int to an int conversion error.

Why is this wrong ? And what is the best way to achieve the expected outcome here?

Comment: If you are looking to pass NULL as an option, have you looked into using pointers over references? http://stackoverflow.com/a/57492/1658810

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in order to pass variable by reference it has to exist, passing 0 or `NULL` means you're sending in a constant. You cannot edit the value of a constant, as it is actualy not a variable.

As for solving your problem, you probaby should use pointers to achieve that, then check if the pointer is set to 0, `NULL` or if you use C++11, `nullptr`

Answer (score 3):

A regular `int&` means that it needs to be assigned to a variable already; it needs to be an `lvalue`.

`0` is not assigned to a variable; it's a "free variable," which means that it's unattached to a label. This means that it's an `rvalue`, a temporary variable that is not bound to a variable. It's denoted by `int&&`.

`rvalue`s can be converted to `lvalue`s if you make it `const int&`. It makes sense that a constant can be converted to a `reference to int constant` (reading right to left).

However, that would be pointless, as you want to *modify* the variable; therefore, the answer is to follow your own convention and don't pass in things that are not already in "existence" and bound to a label/name, like constants or moved variables.

Answer (score 3):

Consider this much simpler example:

```
test_fn(int& ref)
{
    ref = 3;
}
int main() {
    test_fn(0);
}
```

This is effectively trying to set 0 to 3. i.e:

```
int main() {
    0 = 3;
}
```

But that's nonsense. An `int &` (as opposed to a `const int&`) can only accept something that is modifiable.

(As @nogeek001 points out, `const int&` wouldn't allow us to modify ref anyway.)

Comment: (as opposed to a const int&) ? Using a const int& however will not let the function modify the ref value - correct?

Answer (score 2):

As others have stated, you can't pass a literal as a reference.

What you can do is pass an address, and then check if it is NULL within the function:

```
test_fn(int a, int b, inc , int d, int e, int* ref)
{
    int someValue = (a*b+c)*(d+e);
    if ( ref )
       *ref = someValue;
}
//...
test_fn(1,2,3,4,5,0);
int value = 0;
test_fn(1,2,3,4,5, &value)
```

Answer (score 0):

ref is a reference not a pointer. 0 may be passed if it were, meaning a pointer to null; reference can't point to nothing and must be bound to an lvalue.